# How do I hide name surname information with substr?

Tags: php, wordpress, substr

My code allows me to hide the name Surname information with stars. But its output is as nameSurname >> n ****** e. I want it to be n **** S **** e. So I want the first letter of the last name not to be hidden. How can I do that?

```php
$len = strlen($data->userFullName);
$yildizlanmis =  substr($data->userFullName, 0, 1).str_repeat('*', $len - 2).substr($data->userFullName, $len - 1, 1); //NameSurname >> N*******e
```

Comment: If you want to have that output, you need to separate the full name into first and last name and do the process on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would look something like this:
First separate the name at spaces (`explode($name, " ")`), iterate over these separated sections, add the first letter, then the remaining asterisks:

```php
// Your name
$name = "John Doe";

// Split name at ' '
// -> "John", "Doe"
$name_fragments = explode(" ", $name);

// Loop over "John" and "Doe"
$result = "";
foreach ($name_fragments as $fragment) {
    if (strlen($result) !== 0) {
        $result .= " ";
    }

    // Add clear first letter
    $result .= $fragment[0];

    // Add asterisks
    $result .= str_repeat("*", strlen($fragment) - 1);
}

echo ($result);
// J*** D**
```